# Catching all failures in Jasmine Protractor spec tests

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

I want to be able to catch any and all failures within my specs and log it into my Test Rail integration. I have this pattern currently where I wrap all the tests in a `try/catch` and on the CATCH, I mark the test as FAILURE and add it to the results array. Inside the `afterAll` it will then send all these results to Test Rail's API.

This all works mostly correct. However, occasionally one of my tests will fail but will NOT trigger the `catch` part of the code. My spec file will proceed all the way to the `done()` and finish the full test and THEN will show my failure once the code gets to the `AfterAll` section.

I assume this is because the `expect(lookForSomeObject)` is still processing/looking in the background and it doesn't finally finish doing its thing until the spec file gets to the `AfterAll` section.

How can I update this pattern to be better.

```
afterAll(async () => {
    var r = await tr.addResultsForCases(testCases);
});

it('Verifies Search', async (done) => {
        var testCaseInfo: AddResultForCase = {
            case_id: 75
        }

        try {
            const locatorSearchBarInput = await loc.locatorSearchBarInput();
            await waitToBeDisplayed(locatorSearchBarInput);
            await locatorSearchBarInput.sendKeys('35011');
            const locatorSearchButton = await loc.locatorSearchButton();
            await waitToBeDisplayed(locatorSearchButton);
            await click(locatorSearchButton);

            await expect(await loc.locatorSearchBarText()).toBeDisplayed();

            testCaseInfo.status_id = TestRailStatus.Passed;
            testCases.results.push(testCaseInfo);
            done();
        } catch (e) {
            testCaseInfo.status_id = TestRailStatus.Failed;
            testCases.results.push(testCaseInfo);
            done.fail(e);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would get rid of `try/catch`
2. Add `case_id` into your `it` description at the env like so `Verifies Search @75`
3. Create your own custom jasmine reporter as described here https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/custom_reporter
4. register it within your onPrepare()
5. `specDone` function will take `spec` parameter (or `result`, whatever you call it). Then add this snippet

```
specDone: function(spec) {
  if (spec.status === 'passed') {
    // do anything on success
  } else if (spec.status === 'failed') {
    let case_id = spec.description.match(/@([^@]*$)/)[1];
    // report your case_id as failed
  } else {
    // block for skipped test cases (marked by `xit` or `xdescribe`)
  }
}
```

That's it. No need to add your handling to each test case anymore.

Comment: This looks perfect! However, i got it working for two of my tests, but one of the tests it just hangs there. Never gets to the `specDone` function. I believe it's because the spec test can not find a specific element. I've waited for 3 minutes with no error or `specDone` action

Comment: ^^ found the issue from my comment above ^^ 
I was passing the `done` function argument into the spec test and I never called the function `done()` to let Jasmine know the test was over. Removing that `done` at the top of the spec fixed the issue.

Comment: @MaylorTaylor so eventually this works for you? if yes, can you accept the answer

Comment: Adding API calls into the `specDone` function works perfectly fine; however, when I try and add the same API call to Test Rail in my `suiteDone` function, it seems to exit the javascript program before it finishes the API call/promise to Test Rail. 

I'd really rather call the API in the `suiteDone` function to reduce the number of API calls I'm using -- any help here?

Comment: there is a solution but it requires a lot of coding. A short way is to add `browser.sleep` in `onComplete`